# Why does my attempt to add to a vector within struct within a vector within a struct fail?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm having this issue for a while and I would like an opinion on this. If you have any better way of doing it, please tell me. 
Everything works well except when I try to access the vector for the items inside an entity it never executes. Always says it is empty.

```
struct sObj{
    char itemName[64];
    int  itemStrenght;
};

struct sEnt{
    char entityName[64];
    vector<sObj> entityItems;
};

class cTemp{
public:
    void addEntity(sEnt entity){ entityList.push_back(sEnt); }
    void addItemToEnt(char* entityName, sObj itemDetails);
    void setAllItemStrenght(char* itemName, int newStr);
private:
    vector<sEnt> entityList;
};

void cTemp::addItemToEnt(char* entityName, sObj itemDetails){
    for(auto m : entityList){
        if(!_stricmp(m.entityName, entityName)){
            m.entityItems.push_back(itemDetails);
            m.entityItems.push_back(itemDetails); // just for testing
            msgBox("Item count: %i", m.entityItems.size()); // is working
        }
    }
}

void cTemp::setAllItemStrenght(char* itemName, int newStr){
    for(auto m : entityList){
        msgBox("Item count: %i", m.entityItems.size()); // returns 0
        for(auto n : m.entityItems){
            // never gets executed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do call `addItemToEnt`? If the vector is empty, maybe it's because you never fill it.

Comment: By the way, you should use `std::string`

Comment: I do call everything accordingly. The code posted above is just an example of my issue. Not the actual code, since I wanted to make it short for the post. The exact problem has been answered by Frank. And @GuillaumeRacicot , possibly. But the way I have written everything until now, uses char. And it does work now. I will take your advice and integrate it though. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
void cTemp::addItemToEnt(char* entityName, sObj itemDetails){
    for(auto m : entityList){
```

Your loop is working on values copied from `entryList`, not references to them. You want:

```
for(auto& m : entityList){
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally overlooked that. You just saved me a lot of time! I will accept your answer as soon as I can!